# Open and Use a TCP Port

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, tcp, ports

I need to transfer data between several computers in a network using my app. I thought of using TCP ports. Are there any tutorials on how to open and use them? I only want to make a file transfer and chat app that works offline.

Comment: Files and Strings.. what kind of Strings.. are you talking Messages, and files ie .txt or .doc ect.... you must be specific here because we are not mind readers.. and you will get numerous suggestions that will become overwhelming to you.. just an FYI

Comment: So basically you want to stream Text / Strings and store them in a file ...??

Comment: Look at the links that the others have posted below.. this should be a great place to start.. it sounds like you are looking for a quick solution .. you have to start with something and try on  your own.. otherwise how will you be able to understand what it is you are doing.. let alone what we are doing if we just paste the anwser for you.. good luck ...

Comment: It's basically a file transfer and chat app. I hope you understood now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are several examples. Between all of these, you should be able to get what you need.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/realtimeapp.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you look at the documentation for [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) and [`TcpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx), both of which include examples.

It's hard to give a more specific recommendation without a more specific question - are you trying to create your own protocol on top of TCP/IP, or implement an existing one? If it's an existing one, there may well be a higher-level API already available.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [TcpChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.tcp.tcpchannel.aspx) class to open TCP ports and *expose* methods/functions in your Application to OTHER applications.

Advantage: Allows your application to behave like a "webservice"

Disadvantage: Client applications must know the function/method prototype

good luck!